# Python 3 - Initiating a list with multiple dictionaries

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

Is there a way to initiate a list with multiple dictionaries (between 30 and 50 dictionaries)?

Instead of doing:

```
list_of_dicts = [{}, {}, {}, {}, {} ... 32 to 50 times]
```

Thanks!

Comment: The linked question was the very first Google result with a search of "python list of empty dictionaries".

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, StackOverflow should do a better job of populating the "already answered questions" when someone begins to type a question.  Even though that was the first Google response, it did not pop up here as an existing question.

Comment: Are you really trying to tell me that it's SO's fault that you didn't even try Google first? I consider that the absolute bare minimum of research effort. There wasn't even any fancy syntax like `site:` or `""` necessary here.

Comment: No, you are correct.  It is my fault that I did not try Google first, however, that is not the purpose of my reply.  I am simply stating that SO has some improvements to make especially if I didn't use any fancy syntax like you stated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> list_of_dicts = [{} for i in range(32)]
>>> len(list_of_dicts)
32
>>> list_of_dicts[0]
{}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!